# How do Arc Grids and file geodatabase rasters differ?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, file-geodatabase, esri-grid-format

I know that they are stored differently, but I'm interested in comparisons such as storage capabilities, access speed and data types.  I've searched the web but haven't found any such technical comparisons...

Comment: Both of these are older technologies (okay, *ancient* and older).  The current focus is on mosaic datasets, which use rasters in modern file formats (for which there *are* plenty of comparisons).

Comment: Ummm, I remember when Grids first came out.  Those were pretty heady days!  :)

Comment: Yeah, that was one of my first trips back to Redlands, for the 5.1 Beta training. Still, if you remember that, then you remember that grids have two 32-bit flavors (int and float), with some lossless compression  while geodatabase rasters support 1-,4-,8-,16-,32-,64-, and128-bit data (signed,unsigned,float and complex) in multiple bands with lossy and lossless compression.  I've never seen any performance benchmarking.